# Angular finalize doesn't work inside pipe with switchMap

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

After getting confirmation from the user, I want the process to start and the modal to remain busy until the process is finished. Bu the code below doesn't work this way. Only if the request returns an http error from service then isModalBusy turns into false. Other cases it keeps its condition.
I got the code from the theme documentation that i use and im not completely aware what mapSwitch used for in this code. I would be glad if someone explain why and what to do in order to make it work.

```
run() {
        let inputParams = JSON.stringify(this.paramsInput);

        this.confirmation.warn(
            'RunConfirmationMessage',
            'AreYouSure',
            {messageLocalizationParams: []}
        ).pipe(
            // take(1)  when i put take(1) here it works tho,
            filter(status => status === Confirmation.Status.confirm),
            switchMap(() => {
                this.workOutput = {
                    success: true,
                    consoleOutput: "Executing now..."
                }
                this.activeTabId = 1;
                this.isModalBusy = true;
                return this.processService.doWork({work: this.work, workParams: inputParams});
            }),
            finalize(() => {
                this.isModalBusy = false
            }),
        ).subscribe({
            next: (result) => this.workOutput = result,
            error: (error: HttpErrorResponse) => this.workOutput = {success: false, errorMessage: error.message} as WorkOutput,
        });
    }
```

I got the code from the theme documentation that i use and im not completely aware what mapSwitch used for in this code. I would be glad if someone explain why and what to do in order to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

@Andreas is correct with regards to why `take(1)` works. To give some more context around `switchMap`, your `this.confirmation.warn` returns an Observable stream (presumably of type `Observable<Confirmation>` based on your code) but later in the pipe the source observable changes.

In your code, any values emitted by `this.confirmation.warn` will be processed by each operator in the `pipe()` block:

```js
.pipe(
  // take the first value emitted from warn()
  take(1),
  
  // ignore any values emitted unless status matches what you're looking for
  filter(status => status === Confirmation.Status.confirm),
  
  // switchMap changes the focus of the stream - this pipe no 
  // longer worries about the value emitted by warn() and instead 
  // is calling a different observable. The value(s) returned by doWork()
  // will be passed down the pipe going forward.
  switchMap(() => {
    this.workOutput = {
      success: true,
      consoleOutput: "Executing now..."
    }
    this.activeTabId = 1;
    this.isModalBusy = true;
    return this.processService.doWork({work: this.work, workParams: inputParams});
  }),

  // if the Observable completes, then this operator will run. take(1) 
  // ensures that only one value will be evaluated in the pipe, then the
  // Observable completes.
  // 
  // this is NOT needed if you choose to use the `complete` function in the
  // subscribe block in the next example
  finalize(() => {
    this.isModalBusy = false
  }),
)
```

To change `isModalBusy` regardless of success or error, you could put it in both the `complete` and `error` functions in your subscription:

```js
  subscribe({
   // once each value is emitted from the pipe, this will run
   next: (result) => this.workOutput = result,
   
   // you're already handling errors from the pipe
   error: (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
     
     // make sure isModalBusy is taken care of
     this.isModalBusy = false;

     return this.workOutput = {success: false, 
       errorMessage: error.message} as WorkOutput,
     }
   }),

  // like finalize, anything in here will run _once_ on successful completion
  // of the observable.
  complete: () => {
    this.isModalBusy = false;
  })
```

Comment: Thanks for great explanation. I had been worried about if switchMap part was neccesayr so far, i didn't wanted to make changes since its like this in documentation as well but the 2nd solution that you wrote made me feel good.

Answer (score 0):

In order for [finalize](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/utility/finalize) to be called, the observable must complete. That's why take 1 works for you. Because take 1 will give one emission and terminate the stream.([Take emits provided number of values before completing.](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/take#emit-provided-number-of-values-before-completing.)). In your example, the observable doesn't complete(your subscription still expects future values)